# Sum of a value which is in the inner join

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
select @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '')  + (S.SubCategoryName+ '|' + CAST(R.RatingValue as varchar(5)))
from dbo.tblQuestions Q
        inner join dbo.tblSubCategory S on Q.SubCategoryId=S.SubCategoryId
        inner join dbo.tblRatings R on R.QuestionId=Q.QuestionId
        inner join dbo.tblReviews RR ON R.ReviewId=RR.ReviewId
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblCompanies C ON C.CompanyId=RR.CompanyId     
where C.CompanyId=7
```

How do I sum the rating value?

Comment: Please post this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Voting to migrate to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Rating of what? Do you want to get sum of all rating values for specified company?

If so, try this:

```
select @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '')  + (S.SubCategoryName+ '|' + CAST(R.RatingValue as varchar(5))),
SUM(R.RatingValue) as ratingSum
from dbo.tblQuestions Q
        inner join dbo.tblSubCategory S on Q.SubCategoryId=S.SubCategoryId
        inner join dbo.tblRatings R on R.QuestionId=Q.QuestionId
        inner join dbo.tblReviews RR ON R.ReviewId=RR.ReviewId
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblCompanies C ON C.CompanyId=RR.CompanyId     
where C.CompanyId=7
group by C.CompanyId
```